# set position of image in gallery android

Tags: android

I have an android application which has a Gallery. When the application run the images views in the middle of the screen, put I want to start the view from the left of screen.

I tried all the layout params like padding, margin, gravity and setSpacing, all of them not working to set the position of image to the left top of the linear layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<uk.co.senab.photoview.sample.HackyViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="404dp"
    android:layout_weight="3" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/actionBar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Gallery
        android:id="@+id/gallery1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: So then you haven't shown your layout file for adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

1) You need `RelativeLayout` as parent.

2) Set attributes to your images view

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

p.s. show xml code of your layout

Comment: ImageView imageView = new ImageView(_context);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(175,75);
   params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT,RelativeLayout.TRUE);
imageView.setImageResource(imageIds[postion]);
imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
imageView.setLayoutParams(params1);

Comment: @KhaledHayek what type of layout is parent? Linear or Relative? You can did it only if relative.